# Индекс выделенного элемента

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как по событию `TreeView_SelectedItemChanged` получить индекс выделенного элемента?

Comment: Скорее всего вам не нужен _индекс_ выделенного элемента. Работать вы всё равно будете с _самим_ элементом, а он доступен и так.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить индекс надо пронумеровать узлы:

XML

```
<TreeView Name="SomeTreeView" TreeViewItem.Selected="OnItemSelected" />
```

C#

```
int index = -1;

private void OnItemSelected(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var item in SomeTreeView.Items) {
        if (item == SomeTreeView.SelectedItem) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }    
}
```

Чтобы получить сам выделенный элемент, можно делать так:

XML

```
<TreeView Name="SomeTreeView" TreeViewItem.Selected="OnItemSelected" />
```

C#

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    SomeTreeView.Tag = e.OriginalSource;
}
```

И далее, где угодно в коде:

```
 TreeViewItem tvi = SomeTreeView.Tag as TreeViewItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто treeView.SelectedNode.Index. А вообще посмотрите какие поля у параметра e обработчика есть, обычно все там.

Comment: Да, но в WPF SelectNode нет. Source, OriginalSource, RoutedEvent, Handled с помощью них я индекс не получу.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил тег wpf. А там вообще у узла есть индекс. Может treeView1.SelectedValuePath подойдет? Из всех индексов я шашел только TabIndex, но это явно не то что Вам надо.